# Is the residue theory of complex-valued analytic functions related to abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, quotient-spaces

Can we relate residue theory to abstract algebra, for example residue fields, or quotient groups and ideals? Is the name just a coincidence, or can I imagine the residue of a function $\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ at a point as some sort "remainder"?

Comment: You should better think it is not related.

Comment: You can define residues in algebraic geometry as a coefficient of 1/(x-a), or more abstractly using traces if you are not working over an algebraically closed field. (See Serre's book Algebraic Groups and Class Fields.) So the concept can certainly be studied in abstract algebra. But don't think the name comes from a connection to residue rings.